# Kivy: AttributeError: '...' object has no attribute '...', but it has

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this `TaskTemplate` with some Buttons, TexInput, etc. I will put just a piece of code for an easy understanding.

```
class TaskTemplate(BoxLayout, Button):
    task_name = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super(TaskTemplate, self).__init__()
        self.update_state = 'down'
```

```
<TaskTemplate>:
    RelativeLayout:
        CheckBox:
            state: root.update_state
```

If I use `TaskTemplate` as root class it works, I can change the state of the CheckBox with that parameter.
If I add `TaskTemplate` here:

```
MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: here_add_task_template
```

I get this error which has no end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 240, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\middleScreen.kv", line 122, in <module>
     state: root.update_state
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'TaskTemplate' object has no attribute 'update_state'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 694, in _apply_rule
     value, bound = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 243, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\middleScreen.kv", line 122:
 ...
     120:#                root.update_index()
     121:#                root.save_in_json(self)
 >>  122:            state: root.update_state
     123:
     124:        Button:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'TaskTemplate' object has no attribute 'update_state'
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 240, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\middleScreen.kv", line 122, in <module>
     state: root.update_state
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\main.py", line 246, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 341, in mainloop
     self.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\barbu\OneDrive\Desktop\Final App 2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 757, in mainloop
     if self.dispatch('on_key_down', key,
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `update_state` is just an instance variable of `TaskTemplate`. So using `state: root.update_state` in your `kv` just sets the initial `state` of the `CheckBox`. Changing that variable will have no effect on the `CheckBox`. If you want the `CheckBox` to reflect changes to the value of `update_state`, then you have two choices.

1. Write python code that will update the `CheckBox` whenever you change the value of `update_state`.
2. Change `update_state` to a `Property`. Then `kv` will add the binding to update the `CheckBox` whenever `update_state` is changed.

In order to implement #2 above simply change:

```
class TaskTemplate(BoxLayout, Button):
    task_name = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super(TaskTemplate, self).__init__()
        self.update_state = 'down'
```

to:

```
class TaskTemplate(BoxLayout, Button):
    update_state = StringProperty('down')
    task_name = StringProperty()
```

Note: unless you have something more planned for `TaskTemplate`, there is no need for it to extend `Button`.

Comment: A little bit of adaptation and works and now I understand what really Properties are. But if "update_state" is initially down, it cals CheckBox's "on_active". Is this normal? I have there others functions and it keeps call them. That initial "update_state" i upload from a dict. and I don't want to activate any functions

Comment: That sounds like another question that you should post.